# How can I copy a mysql input to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this code that I am trying to figure out and I am not sure how exactly to copy my input from one table to another.

Say I have this input

```
Insert into TABLE Value ('blah');
```

and I want to get that value I just inserted and insert it into another table

```
Insert into ANOTHERTABLE value ('blah');
```

But in this case, I don't know what blah is, I just want to copy it from the first statement. How can I do this?

Comment: Tables are unordered sets so there is no way to tell what row corresponds to 'the insert you just did' without relying on something else. If this is a routine thing you probably want a trigger. Can you explain the context of what you're doing and why?

Comment: I want to set up a trigger statement that when I insert something into the first table, say name, id, and dob, I want to just get the name and insert it into another table, which will correspond to the first table.

Comment: Ahh - you want an automatic insert with a trigger.  I believe you have an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
delimiter //

create table first_table
(fieldname varchar(20));

create table second_table
(fieldname varchar(20));

create trigger insert_into_second before insert on first_table
    for each row begin
        insert into second_table (fieldname)
             values (new.fieldname);
end
//

insert into first_table values ('blah');

delimiter ;

select * from second_table;
```

Output of the above:

```
| FIELDNAME |
|-----------|
|      blah |
```

**Fiddle Demonstration:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4384/1/0

Notice how, in the fiddle, after only doing an insert into FIRST_TABLE, I select from SECOND_TABLE, and it reflects the insert into FIRST_TABLE. After you create this trigger, any inserts that go into FIRST_TABLE will also go into SECOND_TABLE.

In MySQL the default statement delimiter is usually a semicolon ( ; ) that has to be changed to something else in order to create the trigger, in this case I used a double slash ( // ) that is why you see me set the delimiter to that at the top and then back to a semicolon at the end.

Comment: Sounds correct, once the poster clarified he wants a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Your looking to insert from a select statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (column_name)
SELECT column_name
FROM   ANOTHERTABLE
```

As far as "get that value I just inserted" - you'd just run your insert twice of course - secondly on the new table.

You could select the data you just inserted from the database and pop into the new table using a where condition

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (column_name)
SELECT column_name
FROM   ANOTHERTABLE 
WHERE  ANOTHERTABLE.ID = <YOUR ID HERE>
```

If you don't have the primary key of the last insert (as it was auto-increment), you should be able to get it with LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: That will insert every single row of the other table, not just the row reflected by his last insert.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have some type of variable being passed to the procedure or query, then you can just do this:

```
declare

@Blah varchar(10)
,@NewId int

set @Blah = 'blah'


insert into blah
values(@Blah)

insert into blah2
values(@Blah)


--or you can do this
insert into blah
values(@Blah)

--this gets the key of the table you just inserted
set @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() --LAST_INSERT_ID() or MySQL


insert into blah2
select blah
from blah
where id = @NewId
```